# Failed to cast variant value "" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

### JSON Sample data

```
{"location": {"city": "Lexington","zip": "40503"},"dimensions": {"sq_ft": "1000"},"type": "Residential","sale_date": "2016-02-6","price": "75836"},
{"location": {"city": "Belmont","zip": "02478"},"dimensions": {"sq_ft": "1103"},"type": "Residential","sale_date": "2016-10-16","price": "92567"},
{"location": {"city": "Winchester","zip": "01890"},"dimensions": {"sq_ft": "1122"},"type": "Condo","sale_date": "2016-11-26","price": "89921"},
{"location": {"city": "Winchester","zip": "01890"},"dimensions": {"sq_ft": "1122"},"type": "Condo","sale_date": "","price": "89921"}
```

ddl

```
create or replace table sales_json_details(
    dimensions varchar(1000),
    location varchar(1000),
    price number,
    sale_date timestamp,
    type varchar(100)
 )
```

query to load the data

```
copy into sales_json_details from @internal_stage_json_demo 
    file_format = (type = json NULL_IF='' ) 
    MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE;
```

### Exception:

```
**Failed to cast variant value "" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ**
```

How to load `NULL` instead of empty string `""` with copy Options `MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME= CASE_INSENSITIVE`

Comment: updated my answer based on your MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it tries to convert to timestamp before checking NULL_IF, so you may use NULLIF function:

```
create or replace file format JSONFORMAT type = JSON;

copy into sales_json_details from (
SELECT $1:dimensions::VARCHAR, 
$1:location::VARCHAR, 
$1:price::VARCHAR, 
NULLIF($1:sale_date::varchar,'' ), 
$1:type::VARCHAR
from  @internal_stage_json_demo ( FILE_FORMAT => JSONFORMAT));
```

It loads the data as expected.

When we transform the columns, MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME is not needed and not supported. If the primary aim is to use MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME, you should define the sale_date column as varchar:

```
create or replace table sales_json_details( dimensions varchar(1000), location varchar(1000), price number, sale_date varchar, type varchar(100) );

copy into sales_json_details from @internal_stage_json_demo 
file_format = (type = json NULL_IF='' ) 
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE;
```

Comment: I want to use with MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME copyOptions as per documentaton it is supported. With your syntax i can't use MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME as match_by_column_name is not supported with copy transform.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#type-json

Comment: So you mean NULL_IF is only supported when we laod data to a column of type varchar?

Comment: No I do not say that. As far I see, the data is converted/casted to the column type before NULL_IF directive is processed. I suggest you to submit a ticket to support.